# How do I prove symmetry without a defined set?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I have a formula:

∀x,y, z(xRy ∧ xRz → yRz)

If the formula holds for a relation, then the relation is Euclidean.

If a relation is Euclidean and reflexive, what are the steps for proving it is also symmetric and transitive?

I've worked a little with relations but usually I've worked with defined sets and have been provided parameters such as:

R1 = {(x,y) | x + y > 5} ⊆ R × R

However, the only information provided for this is the formula and nothing else.

I'm not sure how to approach this and would love to understand. I'm sure I'm missing something simple here and would really appreciate a few worked examples of similar problems, so I can work this one out myself.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you, and apologies, José. I will have a read on my lunch break.

Comment: This is about using the reflexive property $\forall z(zRz)$ and suitable substitutions and simplifications

Comment: @Henry, I understand that means that all instances of z are related to one another but I'm still unsure of how that can be used to prove symmetry. Do you have a link to anything I could read? I've searched high and low but I'm clearly missing something here and I'm desperate to understand.

Comment: Take the Euclidean property and consider replacing (i) the $x$s with $y$s, or (ii) the $y$s with $z$s, or (iii) the $z$s with $x$s, or   (iv) the $x$s with $z$s, or (v) the $y$s with $x$s, or (vi) the $z$s with $y$s.  Some of these may not be helpful but others will be

Comment: Thank you, @Henry. That, coupled with Daniel's reply, is helping me. I still have a few queries below Daniel's response, if you get a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Symmetry. Let $z=x.$ Then $xRy\to (xRy\land xRx)\to (xRy\land xRz)\to yRz\to yRx.$
2. $(xRy\land yRz)\to (yRx\land yRz)$...(by 1.Symmetry)...$\to xRz$... (by Euclidean on $y,x,z$ instead of $x,y,z$).

Comment: This is wonderful. Could you explain more about what is going on at point 2.

Also, when substituting in z for x - How do you know to do that? I see that @Henry mentioned various substitutions. Is it a case of trial and error and intuition? Or is there some way of knowing that z is the correct substitution before applying it?

Comment: Also, for symmetry, what allows us to  substitute z in for x in the first place? I'm assuming because it's reflexive but I'd love to know the mechanics behind it and not just assume.

Comment: We are not substituting nor assuming. If you have $\forall x,y,z$ (etc.) then this includes all the cases when $ x =z$ as well as those when $x\ne z$.